# Is it possible to see the DNS resolving query in Firefox developer tools?

Tags: firefox, dns, logging, web-development

Using the developer tools in Firefox one can see detailed information about requests to and responses from the webserver (HTTP header and content, timing information, status codes and so on).

I wonder if there's a possibility to also see similar request loggings for the DNS resolving somewhere that are done before the HTTP protocol even takes over? Or is this handled outside the browser (by some operating system component for example)?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

#### Is there's a possibility to also see similar request logging for DNS resolution?

Not using the developer tools.

However, see later in this answer for instructions on how to enable HTTP logging (which includes DNS query logging).

The only information you can get from the developer tools is the "Time taken to resolve a host name." which is in the "Timings" tab.

> **Timings**
>
> The Timings tab breaks a network request down into the following
>   subset of the stages defined in the HTTP Archive specification:
>
> ```
> Name              Description
> DNS resolution    Time taken to resolve a host name.
> Connecting        Time taken to create a TCP connection.
> Sending           Time taken to send the HTTP request to the server.
> Waiting           Waiting for a response from the server.
> Receiving         Time taken to read the entire response from the server (or cache).
> ```
>
> It presents a more detailed, annotated, view of the timeline bar for
>   that request showing how the total wait time is split into the various
>   stages:
>
> [image]

Source [Network Monitor](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Tools/Network_Monitor)

---

#### How can I log DNS requests?

**Solution 1**:

Enable [HTTP Logging](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/Debugging/HTTP_logging) in Firefox. The key bit that enables DNS logging is `nsHostResolver:5`:

> **Logging HTTP activity**
>
> Windows commands to begin HTTP logging (32-bit Windows):
>
> ```
> cd c:\
> set NSPR_LOG_MODULES=timestamp,nsHttp:5,nsSocketTransport:5,nsStreamPump:5,nsHostResolver:5
> set NSPR_LOG_FILE=%TEMP%\log.txt
> cd "Program Files\Mozilla Firefox"
> .\firefox.exe
> ```
>
> Windows commands to begin HTTP logging (64-bit Windows):
>
> ```
> cd c:\
> set NSPR_LOG_MODULES=timestamp,nsHttp:5,nsSocketTransport:5,nsStreamPump:5,nsHostResolver:5
> set NSPR_LOG_FILE=%TEMP%\log.txt
> cd "Program Files (x86)\Mozilla Firefox"
> .\firefox.exe
> ```

Source [HTTP Logging](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/Debugging/HTTP_logging)

**Solution 2**:

Use [DNSQuerySniffer](http://www.nirsoft.net/utils/dns_query_sniffer.html) from [NirSoft](http://www.nirsoft.net/):

> DNSQuerySniffer is a network sniffer utility that shows the DNS queries sent on your system.
>
> For every DNS query, the following information is displayed: Host Name, Port Number, Query ID, Request Type (A, AAAA, NS, MX, and so on), Request Time, Response Time, Duration, Response Code, Number of records, and the content of the returned DNS records.
>
> You can easily export the DNS queries information to csv/tab-delimited/xml/html file, or copy the DNS queries to the clipboard, and then paste them into Excel or other spreadsheet application.
>
> [image]

---

#### Disclaimer

I am not affiliated with [NirSoft](http://www.nirsoft.net/) in any way, I am just an end user of their software.

Comment: Great answer, thanks. :) Good old NirSoft, could have guessed it. Is there any tool that Nir does not provide? ;)

Comment: In Solution 1, instead of using environment variables, it's possible to navigate to `about:networking` :)

Answer (score 4):

You can right click on the column header and enable **Remote IP** to see what address was used for each entry in the Network tab

[image: firefox dev tools dns lookup response remote ip column]

Comment: Cool, but this shows the IP, not the DNS server.